# Ionic framework and ngdraggable drag coordinates issue

Tags: drag-and-drop, ionic-framework

I am using ngdraggable with ionic framework for dragging and dropping divs containing images.

I have a header and subheader defined on my page, while I drag divs, coordinates are not perfectly points to location where I am dragging div, It is dragging down and adding header and subheader heights.

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? Does drag and drop actually works well with ionic on mobile?